# Problem creating an instance of ObjectStorage

Tags: typo3, extbase, phpstan, typo3-10.x

In my domain model there is a property `month` which is an `ObjectStorage` for `bill` elements. Here is how the domain model looks:

```php
    /**
     * establishment
     *
     * @var ObjectStorage<Bill>
     * @TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Annotation\ORM\Cascade("remove")
     */
    protected ObjectStorage $month;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setMonth(new ObjectStorage());
    }
```

Here is the setter:

```php
    /**
     * month setter
     *
     * @param ObjectStorage<Bill> $month
     * @return void
     */
    public function setMonth(ObjectStorage $month) : void
    {
        $this->month = $month;
    }
```

Sadly `phpstan` shows the following error:

> Parameter #1 $establishment of method VIC\Ext\Domain\Model\StorageRoom::setMonth() expects iterable&TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage,
>                TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage given.

Any Idea what is wrong?

Comment: You should add the mentioned setter to your code excerpt. Also you don't need to initialize `ObjectStorage` properties if you properly map them to DB fields.

Comment: Hi, they seem properly mapped in TCA

Comment: Foreign_table = Bill
Foreign_field = StorageRoom

seems right. Thanks for the tip anyway

Answer (score 0):

How to build the construct for phpstan:

```
 /**
     * establishment
     *
     * @var ObjectStorage<Bill>
     * @TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Annotation\ORM\Cascade("remove")
     */
    protected $month;

    public function __construct()
    {
        /** @var ObjectStorage<Bill> $objectStorageBill */
        $objectStorageBill = new ObjectStorage();
        $this->setMonth($objectStorageBill);
    }
```